# how to assign or copy values from command line arguments to the standard input???i have written program but i am unable to do it

Tags: python-2.7

```
from subprocess import call

import sys
import os
import subprocess


if(call("hg clone  --insecure  https://mixmaster.netwitness.local/" + "sys.argv[1]", shell=True)):
    sys.stdin = sys.argv[2]
    sys.stdin = sys.argv[3]

else :
    print("error")
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why the argument is in quotes? Also use % to replace tokens in your string. Change it to this:

```
if(call("hg clone --insecure https://mixmaster.netwitness.local/%s" % sys.argv[1],  shell=True)):
```

**EDIT**

If you want to pass all the arguments separated by spaces, use this

```
if(call("hg clone --insecure https://mixmaster.netwitness.local/%s" % (" ".join(sys.argv[1:])),  shell=True)):
```

Comment: if you didnt add quotes it will throw error.......its syntax ias like that........and that clone command executing perfectly....i m ggetting problem in assigning a value th the standard input??

Comment: If you use quotes it will not take the value of the first argument, it will take the string "sys.argv[1]". That's why it's not working. This code will also fail if you don't pass a command-line argument. You should check the count of the arguments first. What error are you seeing?

Comment: that command executing perfectly.....but i need to copy the values by passing command line arguments to the standard input....please help me......

Comment: How many command line arguments do you need to pass? All? Or just the first one? Your question is still not clear.

Answer (score 0):

[subprocess.call](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) is more easily called with a list of parameters. That way you don't have to worry about spaces in the arguments that you want to give to `hg`. As you indicate in your comments on @Rajesh answer, that you want 3 arguments passed to `hg`, the following should work:

```
from subprocess import call

import sys
import os
import subprocess

cmd = ["hg", "clone", "--insecure", "https://mixmaster.netwitness.local/", sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3]]
if not (call(cmd, shell=True)):
    print("error")
```

If you really want to provide sys.argv[2] and sys.argv[3] as the input to `hg` prompts. You should not use `call` as it can block the `hg` process, use `Popen`.